# Beautify this vb code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 combo boxes with the same 3 selections in each. If the user picks the same selection a 2nd time, the first combo box resets. I have 3 other sections that will do the same with about 15 combo boxes. I was wondering if there is a shorter/compact way to code what I'm doing?

```
  Protected Sub ComBox_GER1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueSelected = ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex

    If ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER2.ClearSelection()
    End If
    If ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER3.ClearSelection()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub ComBox_GER2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueSelected = ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndex

    If ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER1.ClearSelection()
    End If
    If ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER3.ClearSelection()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ComBox_GER3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueSelected = ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndex

    If ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER1.ClearSelection()
    End If
    If ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndex = ValueSelected Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ComBox_GER2.ClearSelection()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What on earth are you sleeping the thread for?  In any case, you could handle all three DDLs with the same sub and just pick the one who's calling to check.

Comment: To show the user that the combobox is being reset.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you are looking to sleep the thread. In any case, you can create a sub routine with 2 parameters which accept reference to the combo boxes and implement the logic using the references. 

You obviously would have to call the sub routine from each **SelectedIndexChanged** event.

Comment: Why would you need to sleep to show that the combobox is being reset? Surely they will know it's been reset when the selection is cleared. You are creating unnecessary lag

Comment: I am using a RadAjaxLoadingPanel to show a loading animation and the sleep to keep it there for a second. Similar to this example:http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultvb.aspx If you have such great suggestions, please suggest an answer to my actual quesiton.

Comment: But surely you would only need to show the loading animation if something was loading - if it doesn't need to load, why delay everything for no reason? Thats my opinion anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
Protected Sub ComboboxChange(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles  
 ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndexChanged, ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndexChanged
 ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndexChanged
Dim ComboBox = sender
Dim ValueSelected = ComboBox.SelectedValue
if ComboBox.Name = Box_GER1 then
  if ComBox_GER2.SelectedValue = ValueSelected then
     ComBox_GER2.ClearSelection()
  endif
  if ComBox_GER3SelectedValue = ValueSelected then
     ComBox_GER3ClearSelection()
  endif
else if
```

//etc

Comment: The code does not work.

Comment: Can I see the entire sub you created?

Comment: ` 'Protected Sub ComboboxChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndexChanged, ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndexChanged, ComBox_GER3.SelectedIndexChanged
    '    Dim ComboBox = sender
    '    Dim ValueSelected = ComboBox.SelectedValue
    '    If ComboBox.Name = ComBox_GER1 Then
    '        If ComBox_GER2.SelectedValue = ValueSelected Then
    '            ComBox_GER2.ClearSelection()
    '        End If
    '        If ComBox_GER3.SelectedValue = ValueSelected Then
    '            ComBox_GER3.ClearSelection()
    '        End If
    '    End If

    'End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're just asking how to centralize the logic which changes the selection on the other combo boxes. If so, that can be done with something like this (as per @imad-s):

```
Private Sub DoSelectedIndexChanged(ctl As ListControl, selectedIndex As Integer)
    If ctl.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        ctl.ClearSelection()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ComBox_GER1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueSelected = ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex
    DoSelectedIndexChanged(ComBox_GER2, ValueSelected)
    DoSelectedIndexChanged(ComBox_GER3, ValueSelected)
End Sub
Protected Sub ComBox_GER2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ValueSelected = ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex
    DoSelectedIndexChanged(ComBox_GER1, ValueSelected)
    DoSelectedIndexChanged(ComBox_GER3, ValueSelected)
End Sub
```

However, there's still the issue of sleeping the thread - especially in ASP.NET this doesn't make any sense.

If you have a lot of these, then another option (as per @dean-depue) is to have all drop-downs use the same event handler. Then, in the event handler logic, loop through all combo boxes and perform the logic on each of the controls that are not equal to the sender object. It would look something like this:

```
Protected Sub ComBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndexChanged, ComBox_GER2.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Get the selected index of the sender
    Dim ValueSelected = CType(sender, ListControl).SelectedIndex

    'Iterate through every list control in the page
    Dim listControls = From c As Control In Controls
                       Where TypeOf (c) Is ListControl
                       Select c
    For Each listControl As ListControl In listControls
        If Not Object.Equals(sender, listControl) Then
            DoSelectedIndexChanged(listControl, ValueSelected)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clearing the selection. I'm trying your 2nd option.

Comment: `Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl'.` On the .SelectedIndex of CType

Comment: You didn't specify you were using Telerik. In that case, the `RadComboBox` must not inherit from `ListControl`. So, change all declarations of `ListControl` to `RadComboBox`.

Comment: No more error, but still is not clearing the selection